# postgresql txid_current returned more than 2^32

Tags: postgresql-9.4

While I was working on this problem:

> WARNING:  oldest xmin is far in the past HINT:  Close open
>   transactions soon to avoid wraparound problems.

I ran the select txid_current() against the database, it returned '7681747386', which is much larger than 2^32.

I'm confused, please help me to understand this situation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. According to the txid_current documentation is bigint.

To get the current value do this:
select (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text::xid

If you insert a new row in the test table and check the xmin you will see the corresponding value in int.